# B2C as IdP for SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, openid, saml, azure-ad-b2c

Completely new to B2C.  Tried both of these walkthroughs, but I'm missing something still:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Walkthroughs/RP-SAML.md

http://blogs.quovantis.com/saml-based-sso-with-azure-ad-b2c-as-an-idp/

Both of these only describe the policies needed, but I'm pretty sure I need to register an app on B2C still?  The problem I have with app registration is that SalesForce gives me a token endpoint URL with a query string:

https://mycompany.cs79.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?so=00D1h000000Cnli

And B2C won't allow query strings in the reply URL.

Is there any way around this?  Salesforce also supports OpenID I think, if that would be better?

**::::::::::::UPDATE 6/22::::::::::**

**SAML:**

I found and realized I was missing a critical step on the SalesForce side: [adding the authentication provider to my domain's login page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_login_id_prov.htm&type=5).  Clicking the new link redirects me to B2C, but I get an immediate error from B2C.  Application Insights shows the following exception:

> The SAML technical profile 'serviceProviderMetadata' specifies a PartnerEntity URL of 'REMOVED', but fetching the metadata fails with reason 'For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

**OpenID:**

Using [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_azure.htm) write-up as a guideline, I've registered the app in B2C and configured the SalesForce side.

Instead of using the Azure AD authorization endpoints, I pulled my B2C tenants endpoints from my meta data URL (login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration).

This works for my B2C admin account, however, when I try try a test user that isn't a B2C admin I get the following error from the B2C sign-in page:

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>   AADSTS50020: User account 'REMOVED' from identity provider 'LINK REMOVED' does not exist in tenant 'MTB2CTest' and cannot access the application '5c8b9f4f-cf28-42fe-b629-b87251532970' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

**::::::::::::UPDATE 6/23::::::::::**

**OpenID:**

I’ve found that it works 100% only for my B2C admin account **if I don’t use a policy**, but doesn't work for other accounts.  **When I use a policy**, only accounts that signed up through the policy can authenticate with B2C (which is great) – but the token doesn’t seem to be reaching SalesForce.  I've created two PDFs showing the configuration details and the results from each method (policy and nopolicy) [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tYAcv3AXHA1mVIbfETWnarAQSwot3_RV?usp=sharing).

Comment: Your think your question is a bit too broad. You could try to be more specific and have more success getting a good answer.

Comment: Do you want Azure AD B2C to be IdP for Salesforce? Or Salesforce to be an IdP for Azure AD B2C? The referenced sample is for when Azure AD B2C is an IdP for Salesforce.

Comment: Yes we need AAD B2C to be the IdP for Salesforce.  Our goal is to have local accounts in AAD B2C logging into Salesforce (and our other applications). 
 Salesforce provides a "token endpoint URL", which I believe needs to be the reply URL on my AAD B2C app, but Salesforce's URL contains a query string and AAD B2C won't let me save the app with a query string in the reply URL.

Comment: Do you want to use SAML? Otherwise, you might want to follow [the "Configure an OpenID Connect Authentication Provider" article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=5), where Azure AD B2C is acting as the OpenID Connect provider, where the reply URL is set to a Salesforce endpoint such as `https://login.salesforce.com/auth/sso/00Dx00000000001/MyOpenIDConnectProvider`.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be SAML.  I will explore using OpenID within the next couple days.  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I've implemented OpenID and it's working for my B2C admin account, but not working for non-admin accounts.  Updated the original question.

Comment: You should configure the metadata address as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policy}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` which `{policy}` is name of your policy. Salesforce should then download the metadata configuration for this policy.

Comment: @n00b Were you able to resolve this issue? I have currently configured my AAD B2C as an IdP in Salesforce (OIDC), however I get a **No_Oauth_Token: Access token was not returned** error if I try to use that to authenticate.

Comment: Did you finally get the "B2C as IdP" part working for all users? I'm in the same scenario and all the info I can find is on how to add SalesForce as an IdP to B2C...

Comment: Did you get this working? We are trying to setup Azure AD B2C as an IDP for Salesforce and getting No_Oauth_Token: Access token was not returned error. There is a clear lack of documentation on both ends (b2c as well as salesforce) to complete this setup.

Answer (score 0):

> Both of these only describe the policies needed, but I'm pretty sure I need to register an app on B2C still?

Not exactly, you no need to register an app at B2C side. All the configuration you do in Policies is enough.

Did you try Salesforce SAML SSO article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_saml.htm&type=5

Check the above article and try to do configurations at Salesforce side and grab the details required by **SAML RP**

I hope by following both [SAML RP](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Walkthroughs/RP-SAML.md) and [Configure SAML Settings for Single Sign-On](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_saml.htm&type=5) articles you can configure B2C as IDP for Salesforce.

Comment: I'm not even exactly sure how to test.  From the SalesForce guide:

`After you have configured and saved your SAML settings, test them by trying to access the identity provider's application. Your identity provider directs the user's browser to POST a form containing SAML assertions to the Salesforce login page.`

But my identity provider doesn't have an application to sign into?  If I navigate to the B2C sign-on URL (https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<tenant>/<policy>/samlp/sso/login) I get an exception. "HttpRequest does not contain any SAML 2.0 protocol parameters"

Comment: @n00b sorry for pointing you to the wrong article :-(. I will update the answer in a while.

Comment: Actually, I found that you can enable an auth provider on the salesforce login page, that will redirect to the SAML provider and initiate the authentication from https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_azure.htm.  But now I'm getting a new exception from B2C.  Updated original question.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled on this question while trying to implement Azure AD B2C as an IdP for Salesforce. We used Open ID Connect to enable SSO between the two. This involved setting up an Application in Azure AD B2C, enabling the read scope on that application, and configuring the connection in Salesforce using that application, a custom policy returning a JWT token, and a dummy User Info endpoint.

Check out this answer for exact steps on how we set up Open ID Connect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61639332/13484109