# Configure Azure AD B2C as Auth Provider in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to configure Azure AD B2C as auth provider to Salesforce. I followed the instructions in http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/kcgTXQytUb6INIs2g3faKg (instead of google used Azure AD B2C). 
[image]

When I click on the test-only initialization URL I get the following error

[image]

My B2C set up is very basic. I just have an email provider and an out-of-the-box sign-in sign-up policy.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the party but I wanted to post here in case anyone else can use this information. We followed the below steps with an ordinary Custom Policy returning a JWT token. Notice steps 4-5 under *Create an Azure AD B2C Application* and step 8 under *Configure Salesforce Auth. Provider*, these will pull back an Access Token from Azure AD B2C.

## Create an Azure AD B2C Application

1. Log into the Azure AD B2C instance you wish to connect to.
2. Go to **Applications**. Click **+ Add**.
3. Add *https://www.salesforce.com* as a **Reply URL**. Click **Create**.
4. Select the new app you just created. Save the **Application ID**.
5. Click **Published Scope**. Add *read* as a scope. Click **Save**.
6. Save the **Full Scope Value**.
7. Click **API access**. Click **+ Add**. Under **Select API**, select the name of the application. Under **Select Scopes**, ensure *read* and *user_impersonation* are selected.
8. Click **OK**. Select **Keys** from the left nav. Click **+ Generate key**. Click **Save**.
9. Check the value of the generated **App key**. If it contains “/”, “?”, “&”, or “%” (there may be more invalid characters), delete the generated key and repeat steps 8 and 9 until a valid key is generated. Save the valid key.

## Configure Salesforce Auth. Provider

1. Log into Salesforce. Go to **Setup**. In the **Quick Find** box, type *Auth*. Select **Auth. Providers**.
2. Click **New**.
3. Under **Provider Type**, select *Open ID Connect*.
4. Add an informative **Name**. This will be displayed to users as an option when signing in. Salesforce will generate a URL Suffix.
5. Place the *Application ID*, from Step 4 of “Create an Azure AD B2C Application”, in **Consumer Key**. Place the *App key*, from Step 9 of “Create an Azure AD B2C Application”, in **Consumer Secret**.
6. Retrieve the OpenID Connect discovery endpoint of the Azure AD B2C Custom Policy you wish to integrate with. This discovery endpoint can be found at https://{tenant-id}.b2clogin.com/{tenant-id}.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy-id}.
7. Use the authorization_endpoint field in the discovery endpoint as the **Authorize Endpoint URL** in Salesforce. Use the token_endpoint field in the discovery endpoint as the **Token Endpoint URL** in Salesforce. Use the issuer field in the discovery endpoint as the **Token Issuer** in Salesforce.
8. Place the **Full Scope Value**, from Step 6 of “Create an Azure AD B2C Application”, in **Default Scopes**. Add “ read” to the end. (The final value should look something like this: https://{tenant-id}.onmicrosoft.com/{application-name}/read openid)
9. For **Registration Handler**, follow Step 11 from these directions: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=5
   a. Note, in case that link changes. You can create a new Registration Handler using the code in this GitHub repository: https://github.com/salesforceidentity/social-signon-reghandler/blob/master/SocialRegHandler.cls. You may need to add u.CompanyName = 'CompanyName'; in the prepareUserData method.
10. Pause here, we’ll come back from **Token Issuer**.

## Setup a Dummy User Info Endpoint

1. Salesforce requires a User Info endpoint. Azure AD B2C does not provide one. You can use the code in this GitHub repository to create a version of a user info endpoint: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/user-info-endpoint
2. This code will only return the claims present on the user’s token. We settled on modifying the code to run in an Azure Function.
3. Whatever your solution, you should end up with a REST endpoint. Place that REST endpoint in the **User Info** field of the Auth. Provider in Salesforce.
4. Click **Save**.

## Authorize the Callback URL in Azure AD B2C Application

1. Click on the Auth Provider configured in the above steps.
2. Under **Salesforce Configuration**, save the **Single Logout URL**.
3. Expand **Communities** and save the **Callback URL** of the Community in which you want to enable SSO.
4. Return to Azure AD B2C. Navigate to **App registrations (Preview)**. Click **All applications**.
5. Select the application created in “Create an Azure AD B2C Application”. Click **Authentication**.
6. Click **Add URI**. Add the **Callback URL** from Step 3. Update the **Logout URL** with the **Single Logout URL** from Step 2. Click **Save**.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to test this login endpoint in your terminal using **curl**, to ensure it is returning the token?

```
curl -v https://<Azure login endpoint> -d "grant_type=password"  -d "username=user@login.demo" -d "password=password"
```

You may need to add additional parameters to the curl command for Azure (perhaps add a client id & client secret?